# C# .Net Core Mongodb Driver returns Name Value pair instead of actual json

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm attempting to use MongoDB with C# .Net Core. For one of my routes I'm expecting the following example

```
{
    "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "title": "Some Title"
}
```

But what MongoDB is giving me is

```
   {
      "name": "_id",
      "value": "57b532aefc19a526b4cf7118"
   },
   {
      "name": "title",
      "value": "Some Title"
   },
```

I'm using the following Query: this.database.find(_ => true);......to find all

How can i get the proper json response without the "Name"/"Value" (What mongodb gives) properties and just return the property name and property value (What I'm expecting)?

Comment: You are getting an array of KeyValuePairs with each pair having a key (a name like _id or title) and a value.

Comment: Right but how do I get it to be just a normal json response where instead of { Name: title, Value: some tile} I want {title: some title}

Comment: are you using MongoClient in c# and querying the data? If so, can you please share how exactly are you calling the calling the db?

Comment: What is normal json?  Show me the specification.  It just isn't what you were expecting.  Maybe your interpretation of json is wrong.